# ARP poisoning detected from our linux laptops and vmware clients

Tags: arp-poisoning

We have a recurring problem in our office network where the Firewall reports ARP poisoning attacks. The source of the attacks are regularly our Ubuntu 14.04 laptops, or vmware virtual machines running on top of those.

---

Edit, more info:

We are running ESET antivirus and local firewall on each laptop, which normally triggers the ARP Poisoning warning. All windows laptops are under domain control, while the linux machines are not.

---

What is a good strategy to get these machines into line again and prevent further ARP attack warnings?

[image: ARP Warning]

Comment: What kind of Firewall do you have and do you have any reason to believe these are actual ARP poisoning attempts (i.e. do you have administrative control over the Laptops?). Do you have multiple network interfaces in the same subnet on these devices?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MarkoPolo, I put in a few edits. The wmware machines are also assigned a DHCP address in the same subnet, which necessarily goes over the same physical network interface card. I do not really have a reason to suspect a real ARP poisoning attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these devices have multiple network interfaces which have an IP address in the same subnet, then it is possible that your are suffering from [ARP Flux](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html):

> When a linux box is connected to a network segment with multiple network cards, a potential problem with the link layer address to IP address mapping can occur. The machine may respond to ARP requests from both Ethernet interfaces.
>
> On the machine creating the ARP request, these multiple answers can cause confusion, or worse yet, non-deterministic population of the ARP cache. Known as ARP flux [13], this can lead to the possibly puzzling effect that an IP migrates non-deterministically through multiple link layer addresses.
>
> It's important to understand that ARP flux typically only affects hosts which have multiple physical connections to the same medium or broadcast domain.

If you have a system which detects when IP > MAC address mappings are changing, a device which announces two different MAC addresses for the same IP address could cause this system to trigger.

As a test, you can modify the `arp_ignore` [sysctl variable](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) on the interfaces and see if that stops the warnings. Setting the value of that variable to 1 (default 0) will ensure that only the interface which holds the target IP address of the ARP request will respond.

To modify the value temporarily, set the variable for each of your interfaces. For example:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/arp_ignore
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_ignore
...
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth6/arp_ignore
```

The changes above will be reverted on reboot, so if it resolves your issue you can make the change persistent by adding a new sysctl conf file:

```
user@host: ~$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/90-no-arp-flux.conf 
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.arp_ignore=1
```

Load the new conf file with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/90-no-arp-flux.conf`

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkoPolo, we'll have a go at this over the weekend and see if we can fix the issue. I'll give you an update then.